# Is there a way to avoid optional properties in React + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-props

Is there a way to avoid having optional `props` in [react](/questions/tagged/react) in combination with [redux](/questions/tagged/redux)?

Let's say I have the following structure:

**HOC that invokes the component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import QuizEditor from './QuizEditor';

const Quiz: React.FC = () => (
 <div>
   // <QuizMenu /> not necessary for this example
   <QuizEditor />
 </div>
)

export default Quiz;
```

**My component with [redux](/questions/tagged/redux):**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { StoreState, QuizType } from 'quiz/types';
import { actionAddQuiz } from 'quiz/actions';

type Props = {
  quizEditor: QuizType;
  actionAddQuiz: () => object;
}

const QuizEditor: React.FC<Props> = (props:Props) => (
  // further code here...
)

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): object => ({
  quizEditor: state.quizEditor,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = { actionAddQuiz };

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(QuizEditor);
```

Now this obviously errors, as the props provided to `<QuizEditor />` are missing. Thing is, I know those props will be provided because I'm explicitly assigning them via [redux](/questions/tagged/redux).

Leaving them as optional arguments works, but issue is, then I have to do further unnecessary checks when working with them.

eg.

```
const { quizEditor } = props;
return (
  {quizEditor.map( //... ) }
)
```

errors, because `quizEditor` could possibly be `undefined` as an optional prop, so I'd have to do

```
{ quizEditor && quizEditor.map( //... ) }
```

Now technically this is only minor annoyance, but an annoyance nonetheless and it feels like there should be some way I'm missing where you can have the best of both worlds.

**Is there a way to combine [react](/questions/tagged/react) with [redux](/questions/tagged/redux) without having to use optional `props`?**

Comment: Here's how https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically

Comment: @AlekseyL. that just makes it so you don't have to type out your props explicitly, but  the props will still throw an error as they will be missing i nthe object declaration

Comment: have you installed `@types/react-redux`? `connect` produces component which doesn't require props provided by "connector" (`InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps` _Injects props and removes them from the prop requirements._)

Comment: Here's quick demo https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-sea-pnf3g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor

Comment: @AlekseyL. Actually that's my bad, I noticed a way on a second re-read, this should be provided in `connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, {}>`with `{}` being `OwnProps` which are absent. I'm not sure why the ConnectedProps didn't go through though

Comment: Have a look at above codesandbox - works even without typing the `connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{ connect }` function needs to be provided a strong-typed argument. Otherwise it presums for the provided argument to be the props of the Component itself, instead of only the `redux` props.

Both examples presume the same header:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { someAction  } from '../actions';
```

---

Here's an example of a solution for component with everything.

```
// could type it explicitly, but this would take forever with every action
type StateType = { //... }
type DispatchProps = typeof someAction;
type StateProps = { someStateProp1: boolean; someStateProp2: number; };
type OwnProps = { disabled: boolean; };

type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

const Example: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
   <button disabled={props.disabled} crazyCustomProp={props.someStateProp1} />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateType): StateProps => ({
   someStateProp1: state.someStateProp1,
   someStateProp2: state.someStateProp2,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someAction,
};

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Example);
```

In case of omitting own Props, you would simply pass an empty object `{ }` in its place instead.

```
type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps
// ...
connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, {}>(// ...)
```